# Constrained Laylout in combination with a ScrollView and with fixed Toolbars

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I would like to have use Constrained Laylout in combination with a ScrollView and with fixed Toolbars at the top and of the bottom. If you do not use a Scroll View than it is no problem. I have a MainACtivity where I do not use a SCroll View and everything is okay as I can just define the toolbars and move them to the desired position in the layout editor. But I also have a SelectionActivity where I use a Scroll View. Here it does not work. I can either have the lower toolbar at the very bottom of the scroll View such that you can only see it if you have scrolled at the bottom or I move the toolbar to a certain position but when you scroll down, the toolbar is not visible any more (also the toolbar at the top).

As nobody has replied so far, I would like to remind you of this question. Maybe if the question is unclear or not answerable, you can also tell me that.

>

> And here is the XML code of the Selection activity:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText">


        '<!--Learning: The following lines define a toolbar -->'

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
            android:layout_width="410dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#435cb53f"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_ToolBar_CocktailSelectionActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="TestText"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.421"
            tools:text="Selection" />

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1000dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.026"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/test_dish_2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.014"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.026"

                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/test_dish_1" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_mainActivity_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="53dp"
                android:background="#435cb53f"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.585"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/holo_green_light" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I would really be thankful for help and appreciate it.

Comment: Does nobody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Is the question not clear enough or is it simply not possible what I want? I'd be happy to get some feedback

Comment: Can anybody help me with this question please? I want to put a Constrained Layout into a ScrollView but the toolbars should be fixed

Comment: Is it not really possible to combine a ScrollView with a Constrained Layout while having fixed toolbars?